# Wordpress Thumbnail URL

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using the following code to echo my image thumbnail url into a custom Admin UI in wordpress.

```
<?php 
if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'full', true); ?>                                    

<img src="<?php echo($thumb_url[0]);?>"/>                                                               

<?php } else { ?>
<?php $url = site_url( '', 'http' ); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>/wp-content/plugins/scp-bookings/custom/images/hotel-512.png" width="150" height="150" >
<?php } ?>
```

However when i inspect using dev tools I can see that the URL is as follows.

```
//www.domain.com/pathtoimage
```

This works fine when i view in the browser but when I view this HTML in the email that goes out, the URL points to a local file and that obviously isnt what Im looking for.

Comment: Check if in your admin if your website url starts with "http://", or try just by using `site_url()`

Comment: It does start with http://

Comment: Did you recently move your website from local dev environment to online environment?

Answer (score 0):

Found out what it was. Turns out it was the cloudflare CDN plugin.

Thanks for your help anyway.